# Prestashop 1.6 Create a default image from a Product Name

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a website running prestashop 1.6+ and what I like to do is to create an image for the product from the product name if there is no image uploaded for the product.

I have researched about this online but I cant find any way I can do this.

When I create a new product on my site and if I don't upload any image to this product then I'd like to show a default image as the product name automatically.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no product image, in a product page you see a static `"No image available"` image. You can find these images in a folder `img/p/` named `en-default-[...].jpg`. You can change these images to other images you like.

Or you can add a product name instead `"No image available"` picture editing your `theme` `.tpl` files by FTP.

For the product page - find a code like this in a file `themes/[your-theme]/product.tpl`:

```
{else}
    <span id="view_full_size">
        <img itemprop="image" src="{$img_prod_dir}{$lang_iso}-default-large_default.jpg" id="bigpic" alt="" title="{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}"/>
        {if !$content_only}
            <span class="span_link">
                {l s='View larger'}
            </span>
        {/if}
    </span>
{/if}
```

**change** it to this:

```
{else}
    <h2 itemprop="name" style="display: table-cell; height: {$largeSize.height}px; text-align: center; width: {$largeSize.width}px; vertical-align: middle">{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</h2>
{* <span id="view_full_size">
        <img itemprop="image" src="{$img_prod_dir}{$lang_iso}-default-large_default.jpg" id="bigpic" alt="" title="{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}"/>
            {if !$content_only}
                <span class="span_link">
                    {l s='View larger'}
                </span>
            {/if}
        </span> *}
{/if}
```

Done!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but i was hoping to replace name for all of the images e.g. home page, feature products and so on. but now I know what I need to change. Is they any plugin regrading this or will it be simple to make this into plugin. If you can help me make a plugin for this

Comment: I don't know such plugin (module). You don't need a plugin, you can change the code in your theme files and in modules templates files, which can be found (or placed) into your theme folder too.